# MVC C# How to add items to a list in the same view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

### What I want to do

This is my first MVC project and I want to create a page that allows users to select a course with typeahead and append the selected course to the list of courses. I can save the added course but I'm having trouble figuring out how to display the added course without having to click the refresh button. I'd appreciate any help on how I can achieve this..

[image]

### What I have

My Classes:

```
public class CourseList
{
    public int CourseListID {get; set;}
    public List<Course> Courses {get; set}
}
public class Course
{
    public string CourseID {get; set;}
    public string CourseTitle {get; set;}
}
public class CourseListViewModel
{
    public int CourseListID {get; set;}
    public List<Course> Courses {get; set;}  
}
```

My view (a simpler version):

```
@using Project.Models.Courses;
@model Project.ViewModels.CourseViewModel


@{Html.RenderPartial("_SelectCourse", new CourseList());}

<div id="listCourses">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("_CourseInlineEdit");}
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function () {

$('#txtCourse .typeahead').typeahead({
    //setting up typeahead source here
}).on('typeahead:select', function(obj, datum){
    var courseListId = @Model.CourseListID
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Course/SaveCourse/",
        data: "",
        data: { courseListId: courseListId, courseId: datum.id },
        success: function () { alert("success");}
    });
});

});



</script>
```

_CourseInlineEdit.cshtml

```
@{
    //set up grid here using `Model.Courses`
}

<div id="gridContent">
    //set up grid contents here
</div>
```

My controller (a simpler version):

```
public class CourseController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index(int courseListId)
        {
            CourseViewModel data = new CourseViewModel (courseListId);
            return View(data);
        }

        public ActionResult SaveCourse(int courseListId, string courseId)
        {
            new Repository().InsertCourse(courseListId, courseId);

            CourseViewModel data = new CourseViewModel (courseListId);
            return View(data);
            }
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The View, is that Index?

Comment: Your list need to be in a PartialView, when you save, you need to update/reload this partial.

Comment: Yes, the view is Index

Comment: @PauloRodrigues sorry, I omitted the details but the list is in a PartialView as well. I will edit my question.

Comment: From your '**SaveCourse**' method use - 
**return RedirectToAction("Index", "Course");** ------------------------- And update your '**public ActionResult Index(int courseListId = 0)**' ------------------- And write a logic to display all the course list when courseListId parameter is 0.

Comment: @Koder101 Thank you. When I use `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Course", new {id=courseListId});` in `SaveCourse`, it kind of does what I want to do but I get two textboxes for `Type Course`. After that it works fine but why does it render the first partial view twice?

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. Create a partial page for the grid, then just refresh the partial
   page.
2. Change your SaveCourse method to return the data you create in index.
       You can then add a result in your success callback and set your content off the result.

Comment: How can I add the result in my success callback?

Comment: success: function (result){  /* result contains data returned */ }

Comment: From `SaveCourse`, I return `Json(data.Courses, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` and I modified the success function to `success: function(result){$('#listCourses}.html(result);`, but it's not working. Is it not the way I can set upthe content of partial view?